# delete empty file link

Tags: debian, filesystems, symbolic-link, symlink

I accidently made a link and can't delete that:

```
big:~# ls -al
total 88
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    27 May 28 18:10   -> /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem
drwx------  8 root root  4096 May 29 01:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root  4096 May 27 04:50 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 18 19:26 backup_big
```

I don't wonna do experiments with "rm" :-D

Comment: Slightly dangerous, but you can always just do `rm -i *`.  The `-i` puts rm into confirm mode.  Simply answer no to everything except the file you actually want to get rid of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash you can do this:

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in !(testfile); do echo "x${file}x"; done
```

and replace `echo` by `rm` (and delete the x) when you are convinced that it works.

If this is GNU:

```
ls -l --quoting-style= # with shell/c/escape whatever fits your need best
```

Or with find:

```
find . -type l -exec ls -l {} \;
```

and replace `-exec ...` with `-delete` (or the `ls -l` with `rm`).

Or you rename it (`mv` instead of `rm`) in one of these ways and delete is manually afterwards.

Comment: find . -type l -exec rm {} \;
did a quite good job. ty!